# How do I stop one of my installed fonts from overriding other web fonts?

Tags: xubuntu, internet, fonts, browser

I installed a font with font-viewer (Helvetica Neue, if it matters) and now many websites (notably YouTube) are displayed with that font. This is especially annoying since Helvetica Neue is a very thin and hard to read font.

Hopefully I can stop it from showing up on the internet and keep the font, but I'm not opposed to removing it all together. But for some reason, I can't find it in my /usr/share/fonts folder...

I'm running Xubuntu 13.10, my web browser is Chrome version 30

Answer (score 1):

Install the font-manager using following command

```
sudo apt-get install font-manager
```

Run the font-manager and there you can disable the fonts you want.

Comment: This is certainly a helpful tool, but Helvetica Neue doesn't appear in there. I tried searching for the name of it and then I tried browsing for it, but it's not there. I verified that it is installed by selecting and typing with the font in LibreOffice.